# ResultSet non-updatable

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I want add a row to ResultSet. My code was working fine then it stopped say the resultset was not updatable.I wrote the test code below to demonstrate the problem.

```
try 
{
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
    String url= "jdbc:mysql://localhost/university?user=root&password=";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    Statement statement1 = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    ResultSet result = statement1.executeQuery("SELECT FirstName FROM Students");

    if (result.getConcurrency() == ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY) 
    {
       System.out.println("ResultSet non-updatable.");
    } 
    else 
    {
       System.out.println("ResultSet updatable.");
    }

    result.moveToInsertRow(); 
    result.updateString("FirstName", "Alex");
    result.insertRow();


    result.beforeFirst();

    while (result.next()) 
    {
        System.out.println(result.getString("FirstName"));

    }

    result.close();
    statement1.close();
    connection.close();
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: When asking about an exception, **always** post the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: tanx. when this code executed, below error eccoured
Result Set not updatable (references no primary keys).This result set must come from a statement that was created with a result set type of ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, the query must select only one table, can not use functions and must select all primary keys from that table. See the JDBC 2.1 API Specification, section 5.6 for more details.

Comment: `must select all primary keys from that table` are you doing that?